# bxSlider destroyShow gone in v4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Well when upgrading from v3 to v4 i noticed that the function destroyShow was gone, how would i go about to remove a bxSlider v4 once it is created?

I tried $("#id").html(""); but im not sure thats the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using destroySlider instead of destroyShow